# Springboot 3.1.0 support for Metro JAX-WS framework

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Is the below class of Metro JAX-WS supported in Springboot 3.1.0 ?

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
```

I have the below code for registering servlet, and after the springboot upgrade to 3.x, the Servlet is not getting started when I hit the endpoint.

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<WSServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        log.info("servletRegistrationBean()");
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new WSServlet(), "/customer/soap/v1");
    }
```